# Why does text in Cyrillic or Japanese contain Latin characters for technical/scientific terms?

Tags: writing-systems, borrowing, writing

Through a [question on a sister site](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/76525/can-bills-the-documents-of-laws-legislation-have-pictures-or-text-only-can-i), I stumbled upon a [Bulgarian document](https://www.lex.bg/laws/ldoc/2134401024) that includes drawings and measurements.

What stroke me is that the text in Cyrillic contains Latin characters when it comes to measurements or references to drawings (emphasis mine):

> широчина (**А**) 1,00

> 1.2. Размери: 18 **cm** х 30 **cm**, 24 **cm** x 40 **cm**, (...)

[image]

**Why aren't equivalent Cyrillic characters used?**

This is also true in Japanese ([**Python**を使用するにあたり必要な基本文法](https://www.kcc.knowledgewing.com/icm/srv/course-application/init-detail?cd=FLM&pcd=FLMC&cscd=UAF30L)), and probably other languages.

It is true that Latin characters based languages do use glyphs from other languages (typically Greek signs in mathematics) but this is rather to make a distinction in specific cases (and use Latin characters for other symbols)). I do not readily see cases where whole words would be systematically used for concepts (such as the programming languages in Japanese), or for units and variables (Cyrillic)

*Note: I would appreciate if someone could put tags that would better reflect the question*

Comment: The primary factor is probably the uniquely hegemonic status the Latin alphabet enjoys. Cyrillic- and Japanese-based keyboards are easily able to input Latin characters, and speakers of languages that use them all learn the Latin alphabet as children alongside their own. The reverse is not the case: the average speaker of a Latin alphabet–based language would likely not know how to input Cyrillic or Japanese at all, and they’d certainly not know how to pronounce it. You won’t normally see comparable Cyrillic bits in Japanese text or vice versa, either.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: But in that case why having, say, `cm` in Latin letters, and all the rest in Cyrillic? Or `Python` followed by Japanese ones. I would agree if all the text was uniform, the question is why mixing both (the end result will be unreadable for speakers of Latin-only languages anyway)

Comment: As a sice question; why is this downvoted? Isn't it a question for the site (I checked the help center and from what I would understand it should be a fit)

Comment: I don’t know much about Bulgarian (which this seems to be?), but Google suggests the local word сантиметър (abbreviated см) is also available. So why didn’t they use that here? I don’t know; you’d have to ask them. In the Japanese example, they could have written パイソン (_Paison_) instead as well, but why should they? The official name of the language is _Python_, in Latin letters, and that’s just as easy to input and read to a Japanese person, so why change it?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I just checked *I am travelling to Paris* in Google Translate and the Japanese translations seems to be *私はパリに旅行します*. The official name of "Paris" is just this, written in Latin letters and despite that there is a local version. Why would a programming language be different?

Comment: Cities and programming languages are not really comparable. While cities do normally have officially recognised names, they often go back centuries or even millennia, and if the city is big or well-known enough, its name will often have been assimilated into other languages and have local pronunciations and idiosyncracies. Names of programming languages, like those of companies, have deliberately coined, patented names that haven’t usually had time to assimilate much yet. Try replacing Paris with Smørumnedre, Qasigiannguit or Cearnóg Sheáin Bháin instead and see the result.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: so why ヌテラを食べる (*I am eating Nutella*) then? A coined, patented name. I tried with *Motorola* or *Volvo* - all of them are translated. I will move that question to the proper site (Japanese Language SE).

Comment: I’m fairly sure you could easily find cases of those written in Latin characters as well. I’d wager the more techy a word is, the more likely it is to be written in Latin letters (‘techy’ having a similar semantic markedness to ‘mathy’), but you can surely find examples of both. It sounds like you’re expecting mathematical logic from language, which you won’t find.

Comment: In Japanese, it is _officially_ a norm to use the Latin alphabet, you're even allowed to write the _whole text_ in the Latin letters, rōmaji. As for technical drawings, they are done according to the international standards which use Latin letters and abbreviations. What kind of an answer are you looking for? We cannot help you believe your eyes, believe the obvious. It is that absolute obviousness of the answer that makes people downvote your question.

Comment: @YellowSky Officially a norm to use the Latin alphabet for what?

Comment: @YellowSky *We cannot help you believe your eyes, believe the obvious. It is that absolute obviousness of the answer that makes people downvote your question.* Sorry but for someone who does not speak Japanese or Bulgarian, it is not obvious at all. I was interested in the cultural/traditional aspects of this usage, and of possible rules. Some of the comments mention them, for which I am thankful. I am glad these obvious obviousnesses are fine with you but not everyone is that bright. Even the start of your comment is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The things you give as examples are substantially different.

I do not know about Bulgarian, but in Russian the measurement units would be denoted in Cyrillic.

On the other hand, the dimensions and sizes would be in Latin because Latin letters are universally used in mathematics for variables. The angles on the other hand, would be named with letters of Greek alphabet. Thus, this has nothing to do with availability on keyboard as others suggested.

Comment: Of course it has something to do with availability on keyboards as well. If inputting Latin characters were beyond the skills of the average user, you wouldn’t see them mixed in with regular text in this way at all, except in specialised contexts, but we do see this kind of intermixing in regular writing. Normal users who aren’t mathematically savvy would very likely _not_ use Greek letters for angles for the same reason: they don’t know how to type them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the plot in the OP is not from computer at all.

Comment: No, the plot isn’t, but the plot isn’t what the question is specifically about. Also, those would be Latin letters here as well since they’re just denoting measured segments. I’m not a mathematician so my context is specifically generic and non-specialised, but I’ve never seen anyone use Greek letters for that purpose (except when writing in Greek, of course).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Greek letters are used for angles.

Comment: Those are not angles in the plot.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the Greek letters are also used for planes: https://sovietime.ru/images/1-AVTOMATOM/geometr-9-10-1978_90ed8.jpg

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This convention existed even at times when typewriters were in  Cyrillic only. Or in Germany when typewriters were in Schwabacher. It was always possible to write the mathematics by hand or using a stencil for hand typing. In books it was common to use different fonts in one document. Fraktur or Schwabacher for German or other vernaculars, humanistic scripts for Latin, various fonts for math.